# Tigase XMPP server BOSH URL

Tags: url, xmpp, tigase

Please help me determine the Tigase XMPP server BOSH URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special XMPP url in Tigase for Bosh connections. Just make sure you connect to the correct TCP/IP port - 5280 is default and the HTTP url does not really matter.

Comment: ok, thank you! but stil nothing is happening when i try to open connection or Prebind using Matrix XMPP SDK

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ejabberd and have no idea about tigase, but with ejabberd it was, by default, set to:

```
http://localhost:5280/http-bind/
```

Maybe it helps.